Why does the Puma Concolor live mostly near the mountain range in Argentina and not in other places of it, when in other countries lives everywhere?
I was watching the Puma Concolor habitat in Argentina, and it lives mostly in the mountain range with a small part in the North and in the middle,
Puma Area
when in other countries with different geographies it covers all the territory, for example it lives in the whole Brazil, Bolivia, Paraguay, Colombia, Mexico, the whole central America, etc.
Why does the Puma Concolor live mostly near the mountain range in Argentina and not in other places of it, when in other countries lives everywhere?

Note that the distribution map you provided is 2d and doesn't showcase differences in altitude etc. so it misleads you to think that the puma concolor (cougar) doesn't live in mountainous regions in other countries as well.
In Argentina, cougars mostly stick to the Andes and Sierras because these spots have the dense vegetation and rugged terrain they like, plus plenty of prey like deer and guanacos. The central and eastern parts of the country are pretty urbanised and used for farming, which means less habitat, fewer prey, and more run-ins with humans, so cougars get pushed out. The mountains also have national parks and reserves that protect them from hunting. In places like Brazil and Bolivia, there are huge, continuous forests with less human activity, so cougars can live almost everywhere. Plus, there's less competition from other big predators like jaguars in those areas.
